# Why doesn't HTML render when passed from AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to pass HTML back to the webpage but it is coming through as literal.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 {{price}}
<br>
    Only <strike>$49</strike> $29
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope,$sce){
    $scope.price = $sce.trustAsHtml('Only <strike>$'+49+'</strike> $'+29);;
});
```

Output:

```
Only <strike>$49</strike> $29 
Only $49 $29
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eyks7zu9/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is your code, with a `<span>` tag added that has an `ng-bind-html` value. I could be totally wrong, as I'm not the best with angular myself, but I don't believe that what you are trying to do will work as you intend as Angular tries to keep the Sandbox model pretty rigid with regards to HTML injection.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.price = $sce.trustAsHtml('Only <strike>$' + 49 + '</strike> $' + 29);;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <span ng-bind-html="price"></span>
  <br>Only <strike>$49</strike> $29
</div>
```

Comment: Ok.  Just a matter of going with ng-bind-html?  And you still need to use SCE?

Comment: Yes to both. If you remove the `$sce` and attempt to simply assign the HTML to the `$scope.price` a security error is thrown by angular.